# Grade this proof of a surjective map from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing

I just received this homework proof back in my abstract algebra class with a grade of 20%.  I feel very cheated, to say the least.  I present it here verbatim for your critiques.  Please tell me what is wrong here.

prove: $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $f(x,y,z)=(x+y,y+z,x+z)$ is onto.

we want to show: for every $b \in \mathbb{R}^3$, there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $f(a)=b$

let $b=(p,q,r) \in \mathbb{R}^3$

$f\left(\frac{p}{2}-\frac{q}{2}+\frac{r}{2},\frac{p}{2}+\frac{q}{2}-\frac{r}{2},-\frac{p}{2}+\frac{q}{2}+\frac{r}{2}\right)$

$=\left(\frac{p}{2}-\frac{q}{2}+\frac{r}{2}+\frac{p}{2}+\frac{q}{2}-\frac{r}{2},\frac{p}{2}+\frac{q}{2}-\frac{r}{2}-\frac{p}{2}+\frac{q}{2}+\frac{r}{2},\frac{p}{2}-\frac{q}{2}+\frac{r}{2}-\frac{p}{2}+\frac{q}{2}+\frac{r}{2}\right)$

$=\left(\frac{p}{2}+\frac{p}{2},\frac{q}{2}+\frac{q}{2},\frac{r}{2}+\frac{r}{2} \right)$

$=\left(p,q,r \right)$

hence, for every $b=(p,q,r) \in \mathbb{R}^3$, there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}^3$ defined as $a=\left(\frac{p}{2}-\frac{q}{2}+\frac{r}{2},\frac{p}{2}+\frac{q}{2}-\frac{r}{2},-\frac{p}{2}+\frac{q}{2}+\frac{r}{2}\right)$ such that $f(a)=b$

therefore $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3$ defined by $f(x,y,z)=(x+y,y+z,x+z)$ is onto

$\square$

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: The only thing I can think of adding is the observation that $\frac{p}{2}-\frac{q}{2}+\frac{r}{2}$ must be in $\mathbb{R}$ (and similarly the other coordinates) since the latter is a field; otherwise I agree that this was misgraded.

Comment: Sometimes the TA is overworked and sleep-deprived, and will mark an unusual answer as wrong without reading it carefully. Best to just bring it up first without feeling cheated or getting angry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is your MSE stamp of approval: your solution is completely correct.

Comment: I agree, and the 20% grade is not really justifiable.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is correct, but it jumps off from nowhere. What you have to solve is the equation $f(x,y,z)=(p,q,r)$, that is the system
$$
\begin{cases}
x+y=p\\
y+z=q\\
x+z=r
\end{cases}
$$
which can be solved with matrices:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 0 & p \\
0 & 1 & 1 & q \\
1 & 0 & 1 & r
\end{array}\right]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 0 & p \\
0 & 1 & 1 & q \\
0 & -1 & 1 & r-p
\end{array}\right]\\[2ex]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 0 & p \\
0 & 1 & 1 & q \\
0 & 0 & 2 & r-p+q
\end{array}\right]\\
\end{align}
This shows the matrix has rank $3$ so your system has a unique solution. By the way, this also shows the map is also injective.

Much less computations and no guesswork. If you want to write the inverse map, just go on with Gauss-Jordan elimination:
\begin{align}
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 0 & p \\
0 & 1 & 1 & q \\
0 & 0 & 2 & r-p+q
\end{array}\right]&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 0 & p \\
0 & 1 & 1 & q \\
0 & 0 & 1 & (r-p+q)/2
\end{array}\right]\\[2ex]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 1 & 0 & p \\
0 & 1 & 0 & (q-r+p)/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & (r-p+q)/2
\end{array}\right]\\[2ex]
&\to
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 & 0 & 0 & (p-q+r)/2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & (q-r+p)/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & (r-p+q)/2
\end{array}\right]\
\end{align}
which means the inverse map is
$$
g\colon (p,q,r)\mapsto\left(\frac{p-q+r}{2},\frac{q-r+p}{2},\frac{r-p+q}{2}\right)
$$

Again, no guesswork.

---

I too wouldn't have graded your solution 100%. Maybe 20% is too low, but I'd have added

> *can you explain why you chose those values?*

Comment: I agree 100%. Unfortunately, some "mathematicians" want to teach beginners to write their solutions in such a way that everything follows Bourbaki-style just by blabla-definitions and to erase all explanations.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg One of my first recommendations to the students is: “Write your exercises in Italian, not in a strange symbol-only lingo, you'll understand your notes when you'll go back to them after some time.” Here I didn't mark the row operations I used, because they're pretty obvious.

Comment: To find my preimage this is precisely what I did.  Perhaps I could have shown this procedure, but I felt it was unnecessary as I satisfied the exact definition (as it was taught by our professor) of an onto map.  Guess I'm still sour about the 20%...

Comment: @magyar The purpose of the homework you were assigned is not to show *that* map is surjective, but that you have mastered the techniques for showing *a* linear map is surjective. So the technique for finding the preimage is much more important than the computations you gave the TA.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an algebra course, your T.A. was probable expecting a proof based on the properties of the matrix:
$$\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 1 &0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right)$$
Proving that this matrix is onto, is equivalent to showing that the columns span $\mathbb{R}^3$ or that the matrix rank is 3, or that the determinant is non zero.

Of course, this doesn't mean your proof is incorrect, just that the T.A. expected something else and mistakenly graded your proof accordingly.